# MUI - Open datepicker when clicking anywhere in the TextField

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, web-frontend

I have a date picker that I want to show when the users click anywhere in the field not just on the calendar icon.

Here's the picker

[image]

```js
export function DatePickerField(props) {
  ......

  return (
      <Grid container>
          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
              <KeyboardDatePicker
                  {...field}
                  {...props}
                  disableToolbar
                  inputVariant="outlined"
                  value={selectedDate}
                  onChange={_onChange}
                  error={isError}
                  autoOk
                  invalidDateMessage={isError && error}
                  helperText={isError && error}
              />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      </Grid>
  );
}
```

I need to do this because if date entered manually, it throws no errors but I get `invalid date` in the form data.

How can show the picker when the field is clicked?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**MUI v5** added the [`DatePicker`](https://mui.com/components/date-picker) component in the `@mui/lab` package. If you want a picker to be opened after when the user clicked inside the `TextField`, use `MobileDatePicker`, this doesn't have the calendar icon though, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69808162/9449426) answer if you want to have one.

```
<MobileDatePicker
  {...}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

The `DesktopDatePicker` however does have the calendar icon, but you have to write additional code to control the `open` state and tell the picker to open when `TextField` is clicked:

```
<DatePicker
  open={open}
  onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  renderInput={(params) => {
    return (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        onClick={(e) => setOpen(true)}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

### Original Answer

You can control the `KeyboardDatePicker`'s `open` state and set it to `true` when the `TextField` is clicked:

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

return (
  <KeyboardDatePicker
    open={open}
    onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
    onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
    TextFieldComponent={(props) => (
      <TextField {...props} onClick={(e) => setOpen(true)} />
    )}
    {...other}
  />
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67053310/material-ui-datepicker]

Comment: i'm facing one issue while using this after this my variant prop with inline value is not functioning properly, that datepicker does to top of the page not get inline with my textField. How can i fix this

Comment: @sagg1295 what MUI version are you using? I'll update this answer to v5 right away.

Comment: i'm using @date-io/moment(1.3.13) & @material-ui/pickers(3.3.10) for implementing date picker. my code is something like this in this codesanbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/67053310-material-ui-datepicker-forked-bvr22?file=/demo.tsx:1159-1190

i'm not using MUI one native date picker using one you have used before, wrapping it in utils basically take care of all issues and you don;t have to handle it by yourself for maintaining logic for minDate, maxDate, errormsg etc everything is customisable.

Please lmk if something is vague in my explaination of my problem

Answer (score 11):

For MUI-X Datepicker v6 using the slotProps it looks like this:

```
const [open,setOpen] = useState(false);
<DatePicker     
   open={open}
   onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
   slotProps={{
     textField: {
      onClick: () => setOpen(true),             
     },
   }}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `<TextInput/>` and not `<DatePicker/>`. If you are on an older version of Material UI that doesn't have DatePicker or just want to use TextInput.

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

const DateInput = (props) => {
  const inputRef = useRef()
  return (
   <TextField
      {...props}
      type={'date'}
      inputRef={inputRef}
      onClick={() => {
        inputRef.current.showPicker()
      }} 
   />
)}
```