# How to add Icon to MobileDatePicker in MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is part of the code:

```
<MobileDatePicker
  showTodayButton
  showToolbar={false}
  disableCloseOnSelect={false}
  inputFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
  views={['day']}
  value={row.value}
  onChange={(newValue) => row.onChange(newValue)}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <InputBase {...params} className={classes.datePicker} />
  )}
/>
```

On the mobile side, he does not show trigger Icon.

How to display to give users a clear indication.

Comment: What framework are you using? Flutter? Or something else? If Flutter, please put [Flutter] before the title of the question. Just put the name of the framework in the title. It would help us greatly in order to answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `MobileDatePicker` doesn't have a suffix icon because you can open it by focusing the `TextField` unlike the `DesktopDatePicker` where you have to click the icon to open the picker. But if you still want to include the icon anyway, just add one in the `endAdornment` of the `TextField`:

```
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';
import EventIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Event';
```

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(new Date());
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

return (
  <MobileDatePicker
    label="For mobile"
    value={value}
    open={open}
    onOpen={handleOpen}
    onClose={handleClose}
    onChange={setValue}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton edge="end" onClick={handleOpen}>
                <EventIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
      />
    )}
  />
);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

#### Related answer

- [How to change the icon in MUI DatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69569262/9449426)

Comment: This is not a best practice.
Because clicking on the icon does not show DataPicker Dialog.

Comment: @Rateltalk see my updated answer if you want to be able to click the icon.

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @NearHuscarl answer if you would like to render only the icon and not the textfield. Replace the renderInput function as below. Will also work for `DatePicker`.
Note: example uses `react-icons` svg icon but can be replaced with mui `IconButton`.

```
import { Box, InputAdornment } from "@mui/material";
import { IoMdCalendar as CalendarIcon } from "react-icons/io";
    
...

return (
    <MobileDatePicker
        ...
        renderInput={({ inputRef, InputProps }) => (
          <Box sx={{}} ref={inputRef}>
            {InputProps ? (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <CalendarIcon onClick={handleOpen} />
              </InputAdornment>
            ) : undefined}
          </Box>
        )}
    />
);
```